# How to debug slow PHP on a Windows Azure App Service?

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, azure-web-app-service

I've installed WordPress on a Windows Azure App Service utilizing the provided template. It works, but it is extremely slow. I am using [Azure Databases MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/mysql/search/?&OCID=AID719825_SEM_FXCUM8UR&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&gclid=Cj0KCQiA3b3gBRDAARIsAL6D-N-NJWSHoceVRF7Li2AdYQFu3l7rx5htnvb0CsWT6sKrl1sNfdq2unoaAqloEALw_wcB) on the same datacenter as the site. According to the logs, the database has plenty of juice and available resources. The site is hosted on an S3 service plan running PHP 7.2 and WordPress 4.9.8. How can I know what is the cause of the slow responses? I need to see if it's a driver, MySQL, PHP on Windows, Plugin, etc? I would love to do this at a low level. I've followed this [horribly formatted blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/04/04/troubleshooting-php-performance-in-microsoft-azure-web-sites-with-xdebug/) instructions, but I don't get any logs.

Comment: I'd start by identifying if there are any slow database queries. There are various tools for this, pick the one(s) you're most comfortable with. After you're done fixing that, check for possible PHP error/warning messages and have those fixed too.

Comment: By the way, I'm not so sure that this question belongs here. You may have a better chance to get a good answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I have a feeling it is related to PHP

Comment: It is, but you're trying to debug a slow site. That might or might not be programming related, depending on the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the built in App Service Diagnostics tool?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-diagnostics

Comment: I have and there is nothing there. That is why I'm saying that I should go at a lower level